# Publishing AWS Nodejs Lambda function from visual studio occupies 10mb instead of a bunch of bytes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-lambda

I've developed till now 3-4 lambdas which have a really small amount of code, but when I check on the AWS Lambda portal it say's it's around 10MB.
I think somehow it loads all the modules that're defined inside the npm package

[image]

even if they're just imported when I reference the aws-sdk.

Is there a way of reducing such a size?

for example here's a function I wrote

```
const Hash = require('pure-ipfs-only-hash');
const log = require('./logger.js');

exports.handler = async (content) => {
    if (content == null) throw 'Content cannot be null';

    try {
        let data = Buffer.from(content, "base64");

        const hash = await Hash.of(data);
        log.info("Successfully calculated hash ", {hash:hash});
        return hash;
    } catch (e) {
        log.error(e.message);
    }
};
```

And in the AWS panel it say's

[image]

Comment: ignore `aws-sdk` in your bundle.

Comment: @hoangdv how do I do this?

Comment: it's up to your way bundle the lambda functions.

Comment: it seems more a VS stuff then me